# How do I customize UIViewControllers you aren't supposed to subclass with iOS 5 Story Boards?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'd like to open a `UIImagePickerController` using story boards and segues, but I don't know how to customize options on a view controller that you aren't supposed to extend. Do I need to do all of this in code instead of using storyboards?

I want to set the `sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` option on the `UIImagePickerController` when I present it in a `UIPopoverController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller that is initiating the segue you can override prepareForSegue:sender:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = (UIImagePickerController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
```